# How to get the rootpage Id in a itemproc function?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I got an extension which uses itemproc functions to configure the plugins.

/Configuration/FlexForms/Config.xml:

```
<T3DataStructure>
<meta type="array">
  <langChildren>0</langChildren>
  <langDisable>1</langDisable>
</meta>
<sheets>
  <sDEF>
    <ROOT>
      <TCEforms>
        <sheetTitle>Allgemein</sheetTitle>
      </TCEforms>
      <type>array</type>
      <el>
        :
        <settings.auswahlKategorie>
          <TCEforms>
            <label>Anzuzeigende Kategorie wählen:</label>
            <config>
              <type>select</type>
              <itemsProcFunc>Company\myextension\UserFunc\ItemsProcFunc->getCategoryList</itemsProcFunc>
            </config>
          </TCEforms>
        </settings.auswahlKategorie>
        :
      </el>
    </ROOT>
  </sDEF>
</sheets>
</T3DataStructure>
```

in function definition

```
  /**
   * Generiert die Liste der Kategorien.
   * 
   * Wird für den Aufbau der "FlexForm" benötigt. 
   * 
   * @param  string_array $config TYPO3 config array.
   * @return string_array         Angepasstes TYPO3 - Config array.
   */
  public function getCategoryList($config) {
        :
```

they assume the root page could be accessed with:

```
$pageId = $config['flexParentDatabaseRow']['pid'];
```

to access the typoscript configuration:

```
$conf = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('Company\\myextension\\Services\\Config');
$conf->setConfFromTsSetup($pageId);
```

but there is no value `$config['flexParentDatabaseRow']['pid']` and so the typoscript from page 0 is fetched, where no typoscript exist.

how can I provide a correct root-page Id (without modifying the sources from the external company)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the installed **compatibility6** extension.

This [issue](https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/compatibility6/issues/15) gave the hint:

> The breaking change no [70132](https://wiki.typo3.org/TYPO3.CMS/Releases/7.6/Breaking#Breaking:_.2370132_-_FormEngine_custom_functions) ("FormEngine custom functions") in the
>   TYPO3 core 7.6 suggests using 'flexParentDatabaseRow' instead of 'row'
>   for retrieving the full parent database row in a userFunc /
>   itemsProcFunc.

There is no setting I need to do. The values are set when the data is received.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure what they meant is that you have to add the configuration to your flexform config.

Should be something like this:

```
<config>
    <type>select</type>
    <itemsProcFunc>Company\myextension\UserFunc\ItemsProcFunc->getCategoryList</itemsProcFunc>
    <flexParentDatabaseRow>
        <pid>1</pid>
    </flexParentDatabaseRow>
</config>
```

Not sure this is the correct way, but I'm pretty sure that `$config` refers to that very config section of the flexform or TCA setup if TCA is used.

Comment: No, as stated in `TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Form\FormDataProvider\AbstractItemProvider->resolveItemProcessorFunction` the config array contains `items`, `config`, `TSconfig`, `table`, `row`, `field` and -if set- `flexParentDatabaseRow`. At least for TYPO3 v7

Comment: where can I configure the data **outside** of the extension code? for example: if I want to configure this value in TSconfig, what TS path must I use?